# How to use Crypto++'s Secret Sharing class to share memory blob

Tags: c++, password-encryption, crypto++, password-recovery, shared-secret

I am building the protocol to share a random generated *n* long password between *k* parties using crypto++ shamir's secret sharing class. The problem is that all examples that I found on the internet about the cryptopp's sss are based on the file sharing but I am not using files to store these passwords. They are rather kept in memory and later send over network.

I found this question on the [crypto++ forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/XEKKLCEFH3Y/) but I was stuck on the same problem as the related question. I cannot figure it out how to overcome the issue with wrongly recovered ls-byte.

Can you please give me some suggestions how to make this work. Thank you